# SQL statement that will sum total up

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am trying to get each category ID to be displayed only once with the total TransactionAmount summed up for each categoryID.

I will then display this in a grid or hopefully get it to be visually displayed in a chart.

Below is screenshot of database
[image: Database]

This is sql code that I have tried which isnt working

```
select * , SUM(TransactionAmount) 
from UserBudgetTransaction 
GROUP BY CategoryID
```

Comment: Seeing `SELECT * .. GROUP BY CategoryID` most likely means you are getting invalid results for every column which is not  CategoryID.. MySQL can use [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct result if CategoryID is unique with it is clearly not.

Comment: Add an expected output also

Comment: Sounds like you have a `GROUP BY` issue. You have to select only the columns that you are grouping.

Comment: change `select *`  to `select CategoryID`

Comment: "Sounds like you have a GROUP BY issue. You have to select only the columns that you are grouping. " it's possible if the database support Functional Dependence  @techouse Functional Dependence is a official SQL 1999 or SQL 2003 standard but the GROUP BY column needs to be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax for the `GROUP BY` is:

```
select CategoryID, SUM(TransactionAmount) 
from UserBudgetTransaction 
group by CategoryID;
```

`SELECT *` is not generally appropriate with a `GROUP BY` (well there is one case where the `GROUP BY` columns include functional dependencies).  In general, the only columns in the `SELECT` that are not arguments to aggregation functions should be the `GROUP BY` keys.

Comment: "SELECT * is never appropriate with a GROUP BY" Well SQL 1999 or SQL SQL 2003 standard added functional dependence which would actually allow using `SELECT *, SUM(..) FROM table GROUP BY CategoryID` if CategoryID is a unique value meaning having a primary or unique key.. Not sure which other databases also implemented this

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . I fixed the answer.  MySQL doesn't detect functional dependencies so I would argue that it is not appropriate in MySQL.

Comment: "MySQL doesn't detect functional dependencies so I would argue that it is not appropriate in MySQL" Well it does from [MySQL version 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) atleast also mentioned in the documentation [group by handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 2):

The  number of column in selection must also be in group by (for most dbms) , you have selected all column but put only CategoryID in group by thats the wrong ,so correct will be like below

```
select CategoryID, SUM(TransactionAmount) 
from UserBudgetTransaction 
GROUP BY CategoryID
```

Comment: Well SQL 1999 or SQL 2003 standard added functional dependence which would actually allow using `SELECT *, SUM(..) FROM table GROUP BY CategoryID`   if CategoryID is a unique value meaning having a primary or unique key.. Not sure which other databases also implemented this.

Comment: "infact mysql from version 8 remove this" not true in fact it's still in the [MySQL manual (version 8)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)